# How do I classify universities per state?

Tags: r

I have a code in R which I have been working on and now I have names of rows (universities) but I do not know which state they belong to so I would like to add a new column into this dataset called state establishing which that college or university belongs to that state. but there are no data about the state either, just the universities or college

here is the code:

```
college = read.csv("College.csv",
                   header = T, na.strings = "?" )
row.names(college) = college[,1]
college=college[,-1]
college=na.omit(college)
# we use some variables to plot and change a qualitative
# variable for a quantitative 
college$Private = as.numeric(as.factor(college$Private))
college
```

[link to dataset](https://github.com/shifteight/R-lang/blob/master/ISLR/College.csv)

Comment: ...uhm, by looking each of them up on Google?

Comment: Yes I guess so but how do I do that? by hand? is there any dataset which are linked to states and universities so that we can use a code to know if that university belongs to that state? we could use a kind of conditional or loop

Comment: _"Yes I guess so but how do I do that? by hand?"_ - Welcome to _data science_ 

Comment: ahahahah , I mean you do not know which state they belong to since even if you had the column state , you would have to classify the state as well as university because it could be that the university does not belong to that state, do you understand ?, what kind of technique would you suggest me to use?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different aspects of this question, including:

1. Where do I find information about U.S. colleges and universities that includes the state in which the colleges are located?
2. Given a source of information, how do I use R to create a data frame that includes the college name and state?

Since "Google is your friend," a Google search shows that Wikipedia has a list of colleges and universities by state.

[image: Google search results]

The information is organized by region and state: [image: List of US colleges and universities]

Data for a specific state looks like this. We'll choose Connecticut:

[image]

Having found a source of data, how do we load this data into R, and include the state name since it's not part of the table shown for Connecticut?

In R we can create a vector of state names, use that to build the state-specific URLs to extract the data, and then use `rvest` and its functions to extract tables and save them as tibbles.

```
# load rvest
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# list of states
stateList <- c("Connecticut", "Maine")

collegeList <- lapply(stateList,
                      function(x){
                           read_html(paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colleges_and_universities_in_",
                                     x)) %>% 
                           html_node("table") %>% html_table() %>% 
                           mutate(State = x) 
                      })
                           
# at this point the collegeList list contains 2 states worth of data
head(collegeList[[1]])
head(collegeList[[2]])
```

...and the output:

```
> # at this point the collegeList list contains 2 states worth of data
> head(collegeList[[1]])
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  School                               Location    Control    Carnegie Classificat…¹ `Enrollment(2020)[4]` `Founded[5]` State
  <chr>                                <chr>       <chr>      <chr>                  <chr>                 <chr>        <chr>
1 Albertus Magnus College              New Haven   Private(C… Masters university     1,793                 1925         Conn…
2 Asnuntuck Community College          Enfield     Public     Associates college     2,388                 1969[6]      Conn…
3 Capital Community College            Hartford    Public     Associates college     4,541                 1992[7]      Conn…
4 Central Connecticut State University New Britain Public     Masters university     13,046                1849         Conn…
5 Charter Oak State College            New Britain Public     Baccalaureate college  2,350                 1973         Conn…
6 Connecticut College                  New London  Private    Baccalaureate college  1,928                 1911         Conn…
# ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​`Carnegie Classification`
> head(collegeList[[2]])
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  School                          `Location(s)` Control             `Type[a]`            `Enrollment (2019)[b]` Founded State
  <chr>                           <chr>         <chr>               <chr>                <chr>                  <chr>   <chr>
1 Bates College                   Lewiston      Private             Baccalaureate colle… 1,964                  1855    Maine
2 Beal University                 Bangor        Private(for-profit) Associates college   229                    1891[5] Maine
3 Bowdoin College                 Brunswick     Private             Baccalaureate colle… 1,969                  1794    Maine
4 Central Maine Community College Auburn        Public              Associates college   3,746                  1963[6] Maine
5 Colby College                   Waterville    Private             Baccalaureate colle… 2,150                  1813[7] Maine
6 College of the Atlantic         Bar Harbor    Private             Baccalaureate colle… 387                    1969    Maine
>
```

Reading the data for the remaining 48 states is left as an exercise for the reader.  For example, one can use the `state.name` object in R as a source for state names for all 50 states, but it will need a `gsub()` to replace spaces with underscores used by the Wikipedia URLs.

Also note that due to the fact Wikipedia is a crowdsourced encyclopedia, the pages for each state may vary in content (i.e. table structures and contents). Additional code would be required to address any state-specific variability in the Wikipedia content.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the approximately 157.5 million taxpayers in the United States, there is actually a database listing the exact addresses of the 6,252 postsecondary institutions in the country as of the year 2022. The list is built and maintained by the United States Center for Education Statistics.

Information about colleges and universities is collected annually and made available through the [Integrated Postsecondary Education Data System](https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/DataFiles.aspx?gotoReportId=7&fromIpeds=true&sid=c6a36c3f-9035-4b02-95d3-ca404cb50fce&rtid=7).

The data is available as a CSV file, which makes it much easier to process than the HTML scraping approach from my previous answer. Since the data is in a single table and colleges for all states have the same data elements, the problem of different data collected by state that we observed with the Wikipedia college information is a non-issue.

The required data is from a survey called "institutional characteristics," and the data file is "directory information".

The most recent data is from 2022, so we'll download it, unzip the file, and read it into R. Note that depending on the age of the data that must be merged with the directory, a different year's directory information may provide a higher match rate on institution name.

```
# download the 2022 Directory information for US colleges and universities
# that includes specific addresses for over 6,250 colleges 
download.file("https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/data/HD2022.zip",
              "./data/colleges.zip",mode="wb")
unzip("./data/colleges.zip",exdir="./data/colleges")

df <- read.csv("./data/colleges/hd2022.csv")
head(df)
```

...and the output:

```
head(df)
  UNITID                              INSTNM                                            IALIAS
1 100654            Alabama A & M University                                              AAMU
2 100663 University of Alabama at Birmingham                                               UAB
3 100690                  Amridge University Southern Christian University  Regions University
4 100706 University of Alabama in Huntsville             UAH  University of Alabama Huntsville
5 100724            Alabama State University                                                  
6 100733 University of Alabama System Office                                                  
                            ADDR       CITY STABBR        ZIP FIPS OBEREG              CHFNM   CHFTITLE      GENTELE
1           4900 Meridian Street     Normal     AL      35762    1      5 Dr. Daniel K. Wims  President 2.563725e+09
2 Administration Bldg Suite 1070 Birmingham     AL 35294-0110    1      5       Ray L. Watts  President 2.059344e+09
3                 1200 Taylor Rd Montgomery     AL 36117-3553    1      5   Michael C.Turner  President 3.343874e+13
4                301 Sparkman Dr Huntsville     AL      35899    1      5         Chuck Karr  President 2.568246e+09
5           915 S Jackson Street Montgomery     AL 36104-0271    1      5    Quinton T. Ross  President 3.342294e+09
6      500 University Blvd. East Tuscaloosa     AL      35401    1      5  Finis St. John IV Chancellor 2.053485e+09
        EIN         UEIS   OPEID OPEFLAG                            WEBADDR                                       ADMINURL
1 636001109 JDVGS67MSLH7  100200       1                      www.aamu.edu/ https://www.aamu.edu/admissions-aid/index.html
2 636005396 YND4PLMC9AN7  105200       1               https://www.uab.edu/                https://www.uab.edu/admissions/
3 237034324 RB27R4GLDKE7 2503400       1 https://www.amridgeuniversity.edu/  https://www.amridgeuniversity.edu/admissions/
4 630520830 HB6KNGVNJRU1  105500       1                       www.uah.edu/                 https://www.uah.edu/admissions
5 636001101 DLJWLMSNK627  100500       1                     www.alasu.edu/            www.alasu.edu/admissions/index.aspx
6 636001138               800400       2                  www.uasystem.edu/                                               
                                                                         FAIDURL
1                             https://www.aamu.edu/admissions-aid/financial-aid/
2                                                  https://www.uab.edu/cost-aid/
3                                https://www.amridgeuniversity.edu/financialaid/
4                                                                finaid.uah.edu/
5 www.alasu.edu/undergraduate/expensesandfinancialaid/expenses-and-financial-aid
6                                                                               
                                                                        APPLURL
1 https://www.aamu.edu/admissions-aid/undergraduate-admissions/apply-today.html
2                                          https://www.uab.edu/admissions/apply
3                                  https://www.amridgeuniversity.edu/myamridge/
4                                                             register.uah.edu/
5                      www.alasu.edu/admissions/undergrad-admissions/index.aspx
6                                                                              
                                                                         NPRICURL
1              www.aamu.edu/admissions-aid/tuition-fees/net-price-calculator.html
2 https://tcc.ruffalonl.com/University of Alabama at Birmingham/Freshman-Students
3                                        https://www2.amridgeuniversity.edu:9091/
4                                                                 finaid.uah.edu/
5                       www.alasu.edu/cost-aid/tuition-costs/net-price-calculator
6                                                                                
                                                  VETURL                                                    ATHURL
1                                                                                                                 
2                  https://www.uab.edu/students/veterans                    https://www.uab.edu/registrar/students
3 https://www.amridgeuniversity.edu/admissions/military/                                                          
4 www.uah.edu/admissions/graduate/financial-aid/veterans                                          www.uah.edu/heoa
5                                                        https://www.alasu.edu/administration/consumer-information
6                                                                                                                 
                                                                         DISAURL SECTOR ICLEVEL CONTROL HLOFFER UGOFFER
1 https://www.aamu.edu/administrativeoffices/VADS/Pages/Disability-Services.aspx      1       1       1       9       1
2                                       https://www.uab.edu/students/disability/      1       1       1       9       1
3                             https://www.amridgeuniversity.edu/studentservices/      2       1       2       9       1
4                             www.uah.edu/health-and-wellness/disability-support      1       1       1       9       1
5 www.alasu.edu/academics/researchcenters/alabama-alliance-students-disabilities      1       1       1       9       1
6                                                              www.uasystem.edu/      0       1       1       9       1
  GROFFER HDEGOFR1 DEGGRANT HBCU HOSPITAL MEDICAL TRIBAL LOCALE OPENPUBL ACT NEWID DEATHYR CLOSEDAT CYACTIVE POSTSEC PSEFLAG
1       1       12        1    1        2       2      2     12        1  A     -2      -2       -2        1       1       1
2       1       11        1    2        1       1      2     12        1  A     -2      -2       -2        1       1       1
3       1       12        1    2        2       2      2     12        1  A     -2      -2       -2        1       1       1
4       1       11        1    2        2       2      2     12        1  A     -2      -2       -2        1       1       1
5       1       11        1    1        2       2      2     12        1  A     -2      -2       -2        1       1       1
6       1       11        1    2       -2      -2      2     13        1  A     -2      -2       -2        1       1       1
  PSET4FLG RPTMTH INSTCAT C21BASIC C21IPUG C21IPGRD C21UGPRF C21ENPRF C21SZSET C18BASIC C15BASIC CCBASIC CARNEGIE LANDGRNT
1        1      1       2       18      16       18       10        4       14       18       18      18       16        1
2        1      1       2       15      14       14        9        5       15       15       15      15       15        2
3        1      1       2       20      20       18        5        6        6       20       20      21       51        2
4        1      1       2       15      17       17       15        4       13       16       16      15       16        2
5        1      1       2       17      13       18       10        3       14       19       19      18       21        2
6        1     -2      -2       -2      -2       -2       -2       -2       -2       -2       -2      -2       -2        2
  INSTSIZE F1SYSTYP                         F1SYSNAM F1SYSCOD  CBSA CBSATYPE CSA COUNTYCD          COUNTYNM CNGDSTCD
1        3        2                               -2       -2 26620        1 290     1089    Madison County      105
2        5        1 The University of Alabama System   101050 13820        1 142     1073  Jefferson County      107
3        1        2                               -2       -2 33860        1 388     1101 Montgomery County      102
4        3        1 The University of Alabama System   101050 26620        1 290     1089    Madison County      105
5        2        2                               -2       -2 33860        1 388     1101 Montgomery County      107
6       -2        1 The University of Alabama System   101050 46220        1  -2     1125 Tuscaloosa County      107
   LONGITUD LATITUDE DFRCGID DFRCUSCG
1 -86.56850 34.78337     107        1
2 -86.79935 33.50570      92        1
3 -86.17401 32.36261     125        2
4 -86.64045 34.72456      92        2
5 -86.29568 32.36432      98        1
6 -87.52959 33.20701      -2       -2
>
```

A data dictionary for the file is accessible [here](https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/data/HD2022_Dict.zip) as a zip file, which can be downloaded and processed in R as follows. The data dictionary is an Excel spreadsheet containing 4 different worksheets, the second of which lists the variable names and descriptions in the main data file.

```
# download the data dictionary and read into R 

download.file("https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/data/HD2022_Dict.zip",
              "./data/collegesDictionary.zip",mode="wb")
unzip("./data/collegesDictionary.zip",exdir="./data/colleges")

library(readxl)
dictionary <- read_excel("./data/colleges/hd2022.xlsx",
                         sheet = 2)
head(dictionary)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(dictionary)                                                                                                         
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  varnumber varname DataType Fieldwidth format imputationvar varTitle                                       
      <dbl> <chr>   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>  <lgl>         <chr>                                          
1         1 UNITID  N                 6 Cont   NA            Unique identification number of the institution
2     10001 INSTNM  A               120 Alpha  NA            Institution (entity) name                      
3     16081 IALIAS  A              2000 Alpha  NA            Institution name alias                         
4     10006 ADDR    A               100 Alpha  NA            Street address or post office box              
5     10011 CITY    A                30 Alpha  NA            City location of institution                   
6     10016 STABBR  A                 2 Disc   NA            State abbreviation                             
>
```